# Output data from mongodb to an external variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

How to output data from mongodb to an external variable. For example

```
let variableArr = [];
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
 
mongoClient.connect(function(err, client){
      
    const db = client.db("variabledb");
    const collection = db.collection("variables");
 
    if(err) return console.log(err);
      
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, results){
        
        results.forEach(item => variableArr.push(item))
        client.close();
    });

console.log(variableArr);
```

The console outputs an empty array. I understand that the problem is async, but how to implement this moment.
Thanks!

Comment: Are there any documents in the `"variables"` collection? You can also log `results.length` and see what is the outcome of the find method.

Comment: Yes, there are variables in the collection. console.log(results.length) outputs 3

Comment: It is about how you use _callbacks_. See [Callbacks and Promises](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/).